# Tensors, showing that $LL^t=I \implies L^tL=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

A problem from the tensor section in my compendium states that $LL^t=I \implies L^tL=I$ needs to be shown.

what I did was $(LL^t)_{ij} = L_{ik}L^t_{kj}=L_{ik}L_{jk}=\delta_{ij}$, and
$(L^tL)_{ij} = L^t_{ik}L_{kj}=L_{ki}L_{kj}=\delta_{ij}$.

My first question is how can one show, or why does $L_{ik}L_{jk}=\delta_{ij}$? The second question is, is this $L_{ki}L_{kj}=\delta_{ij}$ true? (Maybe the answer to the second question gets answered by the first). The third question is does what I've shown really answer the original question? I don't see that what I have done implies what they want, maybe an equivalence?

Comment: no, what you've done is just rewriting of hypothesis and thesis and nothing more

Comment: How should I do then?

Comment: Maybe you should think about them as matrices.

Comment: *Hint*: prove that $AB=I\implies BA=I$

Comment: Thank you for answering, but ss it then really a problem that should be found in a a tensor section?

Comment: It depends on how many indexes the tensor has..

Comment: $L_{ik}L_{jk} = \delta_{ij}$ because you are given $LL^t = I$, and you've calculated that this is an equivalent statement. That $L_{ki}L_{kj} = \delta_{ij}$ is similarly an equivalent statement to what you are being asked to show (i.e., that $L^tL = I$. You have done nothing so far to show that this must be true. Matrices are 2D tensors, so yes, thinking about the matrix version of the problem will lead you to tensor solution. You might want to consider what happens if you multiply $L^tL = I$ by $L^t$ on the right. Then consider what else you can do.

Comment: I did solve the problem by using matrices but can one solve it using tensor notation?